# angularjs with restfull webservice

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to communicate restfull webservice using angularjs.my application located in c://Higi folder and i have created restfull webservice in eclipse now i am using  return

```
$http.get('http://localhost:8080/RestfulAndAngularJS_Server/rest/product/findall')
 .success(function(response){
                $window.alert('success')
});
```

code for connecting with restfull webservice it is possible or not

Comment: My appilication located in c://higi folder in my local machine  but i have created restfull webservice in eclipse it has generated one link  http://localhost:8080/RestfulAndAngularJS_Server/rest/product/findall

Comment: then i have used that link in my js file using below code   return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/RestfulAndAngularJS_Server/rest/product/findall').success(function(response){
                $window.alert('success')
                  }).      error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $window.alert('failure')
                          }); but i am getting status 0 not 200 can u pls suggest me how to communicate to restfull webservice

Comment: You should consider editing your question and asking what your actual issue is.  Right now, you are asking a yes or no question, which really aren't appropriate for this format, but you suggest in some comments that you have some errors.  You should ask about the actual error and edit the question to include it, rather than just asking if it's possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [angularjs with restfull webservice communication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31579682/angularjs-with-restfull-webservice-communication)

Answer (score 0):

If your http://localhost:8080/RestfulAndAngularJS_Server/rest/product/findall endpoint is accessible in general, then it should be accessible via the angular $http service.

You can test whether the server is up  by pasting that url in the browser. Depending on how your server side code is set up with regard to content negotiation, you might get an error back (which error will depend on what you used to build the web service, but at least you'll know that it's up).

If it's up then you should be able to call it from the angular $http service.  If not, then make sure its' running by starting whatever server you are using in eclipse.

If you're sure the server is up and running, your call should work. You might also consider handling the error callback in your $http.get call to see whats' happening there.